# How could you develop a simple DEALER/ROUTER message flow, using ZeroMQ?

Tags: tcp, zeromq

I'm fairly new to TCP messaging (and programming in general) and I am trying to develop a simple ROUTER/DEALER message pair with ZeroMQ but am struggling in getting the router to receive a message from the dealer and send one back.

I can do a simple **`REQ/REP`** pattern with no problem, where I can send one message from my machine to my VM.

However, when trying to develop a **`ROUTER/DEALER`** pair, I can't seem to get the `ROUTER`-instance to receive the message (`ROUTER` on VM, `DEALER` on main box). I have had some success where I could spam 50 messages in a `while(){...}` loop, but can't send a single message and have the **`ROUTER`** send one back.

So from what I have read, a TCP message in a `ROUTER/DEALER` pair are sent with a delimiter of 0 at the beginning, and this 0 must be sent first to the `ROUTER` to register an incoming message.

So I just want to send the message *"ROUTER_TEST"* to my server, and for my server to respond with *"RECEIVED"*.

**DEALER**

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "zmq.h"

const char connection[] = "tcp://10.0.10.76:5555";
int main(void)
{
    int major, minor, patch;
    zmq_version(&major, &minor, &patch);
    printf("\nInstalled ZeroMQ version: %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, patch);
    printf("Connecting to: %s\n", connection);

    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();

    void *requester = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_DEALER);

    int zc = zmq_connect(requester, connection); 
    std::cout << "zmq_connect = " << zc << std::endl;

    int sm = zmq_socket_monitor(requester, connection, ZMQ_EVENT_ALL);
    std::cout << "zmq_socket_monitor = " << sm << std::endl;

    char messageSend[] = "ROUTER_TEST";

    int request_nbr;
    int n = zmq_send(requester, NULL, 0, ZMQ_DONTWAIT|ZMQ_SNDMORE );
    int ii = 0;
    if(n==0) {
        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
    while (ii < 50)
    {
        n = zmq_send(requester, messageSend, 31, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

        ii++;
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**ROUTER**

```cpp
// SERVER
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "zmq.h"

int main(void)
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *responder = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    printf("THIS IS WORKING - ROUTER\n");
    int rc = zmq_bind(responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert(rc == 0);

    zmq_pollitem_t pollItems[] = {
        {responder, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, -1}};

    int sm = zmq_socket_monitor(responder, "tcp://*:5555", ZMQ_EVENT_LISTENING);
    std::cout << "zmq_socket_monitor = " << sm << std::endl;
    uint8_t buffer[15];
    while (1)
    {
        int rc = zmq_recv(responder, buffer, 5, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "zmq_recv = " << rc << std::endl;
            zmq_send(responder, "RECIEVED", 9,0);
        }

        zmq_poll(pollItems, sizeof(pollItems), -1);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls, on the **`DEALER`**-side a series of:

```
void *requester = zmq_socket( context,
                              ZMQ_DEALER           // <--   .STO <ZMQ_DEALER>, *requester
                              );
...
int n   = zmq_send( requester, // <~~ <~~ <~~ <~~ <~~ <~~   .STO 0, n
                    NULL,     //                             NULL,sizeof(NULL)== 0
                    0,       //                              explicitly declared 0
                    ZMQ_DONTWAIT                   //           _DONTWAIT flag
                  | ZMQ_SNDMORE                    //---- 1x ZMQ_SNDMORE  flag== 
                    );                             //        1.Frame in 1st MSG
int ii  = 0;                                       //        MSG-under-CONSTRUCTION
if ( n == 0 )                                      //     ...until complete, not yet sent
{    
     std::cout << "PREVIOUS[" << ii << ".] CALL of zmq_send() has returned n = " << n << std::endl;
     
     while ( ii < 50 )
     {       ii++;
             n = zmq_send( requester,   //---------//---- 1x ZMQ_SNDMORE following
                           messageSend, //         //        2.Frame in 1st MSG
                           31,          //         //        MSG-under-CONSTRUCTION, but
                           ZMQ_DONTWAIT //         //        NOW complete & will get sent
                           );           //---------//----49x monoFrame MSGs follow
     }
}
...
```

---

### What happens on the opposite side, the **`ROUTER`**-side code ?

```
...
while (1)
{       
        int  rc  = zmq_recv( responder, //----------------- 1st .recv()
                             buffer,
                             5,
                             ZMQ_DONTWAIT
                             );
        if ( rc == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << "zmq_recv = " << rc << std::endl;
            zmq_send( responder,  // _____________________ void  *socket
                      "RECEIVED", // _____________________ void  *buffer
                      9,  // _____________________________ size_t len
                      0   // _____________________________ int    flags
                      );
        }
        zmq_poll( pollItems,
                  sizeof( pollItems ),
                  -1 // __________________________________ block ( forever )
                  );//                                     till  ( if ever ) ...?
}
```

### Here, most probably, the **`rc == 0`** but once, if not missed, but never more

Kindly notice, that your code does not detect in any way if a `.recv()`-call is also being flagged by a **`ZMQ_RECVMORE`** - signaling a need to first also `.recv()`-all-the-rest multi-Frame parts of the first message, before becoming able to `.send()`-any-answer...

> *An application that processes multi-part messages **must use** the **`ZMQ_RCVMORE`** `zmq_getsockopt(3)` option after calling `zmq_recv()` to determine if there are further parts to receive.*

Next, the **`buffer`** and **`messageSend`** message-"payloads" are a kind of fragile entities and ought be re-composed ( for details best read again all details about how to carefully initialise, work with and safely-touch any **`zmq_msg_t`** object(s) ), as after a successful `.send()/.recv()` the low level API ( since 2.11.x+ ) considers them disposed-off, not re-useable. Also note, that `messageSend` is **not** (as imperatively put into the code) a 31-`char[]`-long, was it? Was there any particular intention to do this?

> The `zmq_send()` function shall return number of bytes in the message if successful. Otherwise it shall return **`-1`** and set `errno` to one of the values defined below. **`{ EAGAIN, ENOTSUP, EINVAL, EFSM, ETERM, ENOTSOCK, EINTR, EHOSTUNREACH }`**

Not testing error-state means knowing nothing about the actual state ( see `EFSM` and other potential trouble explainers ) of `REQ/REP` and `DEALER/ROUTER` (extended) `.send()/.recv()/.send()/.recv()/...` mandatory dFSA's order of these steps

---

> *"So from what I have read, a TCP message in a `ROUTER/DEALER` pair are sent with a delimiter of 0 at the beginning, and this 0 must be sent first to the `ROUTER` to register an incoming message."*

This seems to be a misunderstood part. The app-side is free to compose any number of monoframe or multi-frame messages, yet the "trick" of a `ROUTER` prepended identity-frame is performed without users assistance ( message-labelling is performed automatically, before any ( now, principally all ) multi-frame(d) messages get delivered to the app-side ( using the receiver's side `.recv()`-method ). Due handling of multi-frame messages was noted above.